# "TypeError: Invalid value used in weak set" while build using webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I'm trying to add scss to the project. I want to build css files from scss ones, but I get an error that says "TypeError: Invalid value used in weak set" since I added **MiniCssExtractPlugin**.
Here's my *webpack.config.js*:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const config = {
  // TODO: Add common Configuration
  module: {},
};

const js = Object.assign({}, config, {
  name: 'js',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../some/path/here'),
    filename: 'main.js',
  },
});

const scss = Object.assign({}, config, {
  name: 'scss',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './scss/styles.scss'),
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(s*)css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../some/path/here'),
    filename: 'styles.css',
  },
});

module.exports = [js, scss];
```

I googled a lot but didn't find any answers.
I use Node.js v 8.4.0.

Console output (There is more, but I think this is enough):

```
TypeError: Invalid value used in weak set
    at WeakSet.add (native)
    at MiniCssExtractPlugin.apply (/path/path/path/path/path/path/path/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/index.js:362:18)
```

PS: I'm new to webpack, so I'll be glad if you help me to make this code better. The main idea is to keep js compilation the same and add scss compilation. I also want to compile included scss files as separated ones.

PSS: If you need more information, I'll provide some, coz idk what else can be useful.

Comment: Related - https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/779

Comment: I downgraded mini-css-extract-plugin to version 1.6.2. This helped me to overcome an error. But I still don't get my css code in styles.css. Actually this is the reason I've added the plugin. Thanks.

Comment: In the related link James posted they say it is webpack 5 only. I think you still use webpack 4.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe the latest **mini-css-extract-plugin** version has bugs. And I tried to use another version of this package. And its Worked!!!

1. Remove your last package version:

   ```
    npm uninstall mini-css-extract-plugin
   ```
2. Download this version 0.9.0 (its worked for me):

   ```
    npm i --save-dev mini-css-extract-plugin@0.9.0
   ```

*optionally (--save-dev)

checkout all versions:
[mini-css-extract-plugin/all-versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mini-css-extract-plugin/v/0.9.0?activeTab=versions)

Comment: This works for me as well. I wouldn't go as far as to say it has bugs, but rather some breaking changes, since `2.0.0` ;) For me, the version specifier `^1.6.2` works out ok!

Comment: downgrading should really be last resort, we should be moving forward and not backwards

Answer (score 6):

This is most likely due to either a bug or an incompatible version of webpack, e.g. upgrading to the current major v2.0.0 releases on webpack 4.

For more information, please [check the changelog](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for breaking changes and fixes.

Comment: Yup, 1.6.2 is the last version that supports webpack 4. If you are getting this whilst following webpack 4 to 5 migration steps and you are getting error on this (https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#upgrade-webpack-4-and-its-pluginsloaders) step, then downgrade to 1.6.2

Comment: It was for me. Upgrading to the latest version of webpack packages fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll need to downgrade some other plugins as well. I was following a tutorial when I had the same error. This is what worked for me:

```
{
  "name": "recipe-blocks",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=default webpack --watch",
    "build": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=default NODE_ENV=production webpack -p"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.2.0",
    "@wordpress/babel-preset-default": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "raw-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.26.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Then Run: 
`npm install`
`npm run dev`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.